# How to sort node resource in index call in ascending order the in service module

Tags: 7, services

Hi I am using [`service module 7.x-3.12`](https://www.drupal.org/project/services). I am able to fetch the node resource in index call on several different parameters and its working fine but I am stuck in a situation where I need to fetch the data in ascending order. But by default I am getting the data in DESC. Is there any way I can fetch the data in ascending order by providing a custom parameter say, sort_by.

Answer (score 1):

It *currently* isn't possible. I have [an issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2537968) and [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/index_query_options-2537968-1.patch) filed to make this a possibility. If you use the patch, it is possible using this query string:

```
?q=endpoint/taxonomy_term.json&fields=tid,name&options[orderby][name]=asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)** Module

> It has currently two features:
>
> - Create view based resource creating Services display in a view
> - Execute any view of the system via views resource call

With the help of this you can create a view of type `service` and you can add whatever fields, filters,sorting you need.

Comment: Be warned, despite being 'stable', I've had quite a lot of problems using that module. I've had to patch it up so much it doesn't much resemble the original any more

Comment: @Bipin K Thanks! but I want to that is there any way to achive the same in custom module by altering the query or somethinkg like that